# Finding load resistance to achieve max power transfer

Tags: resistance, parallel

[image]

```
1) So, to find Thenevin equivalent resistance, R-Th,
   I disconnect R_L and disable the voltage source
   by shorting it out.
```

[image]

```
2) Now I just look back into the network and
   calculate R_Th, which I know R_L will 
   have to equal to since max. power transfer
   is achieved when R_L == R_Th.

3) Now this is where I'm having trouble.  I see:

   [(2k + 2k) || 2k] + 2k
   (4k || 2k) + 2k
   8/6k + 2k
   10/3 k = 3.333k ohms

   But my book says it's:

   [(2k || 2k) + 2k ] || 2k
   (1k + 2k) || 2k
   3k || 2k
   6/5 k = 1.2k ohms
```

So, can someone explain to me why my equivalent resistance is incorrect?  Starting at the right I see 2k in series with 2k, making 4k.  Now, I see that 4k in parallel with the 2k in the middle branch, making 4/3k.  And now since I'm left with a single loop, I see the 4/3k and remaining 2k (top left) in series, as they would carry the same current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the equivalent resistance between those two terminals, I assume that we are connecting a voltage source V across it. Let I be the current drawn by the circuit, then V/I will give the equivalent resistance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE9Mgo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 and R2 are in parallel and same current flows through R3 and R1||R2. so R3 and R1||R2 are in series. Now the current through R4 is V/R4 and current through R3 is V/(R3+R1||R2).

or I = V/R4 + V/(R3+R1||R2).

So the resultant resistance is V/I = (R1||R2 + R3)||R4.

Comment: Ahh, So I made a mistake by arbitrarily combining resistors.  I actually need to pretend a current is flowing in to the circuit and see where it divides, and which resistors are in series?

Comment: Yes. you have to.

Comment: Can you tell me what would happen if you flipped the polarity of your attached voltage source, so that current would flow in the other direction?  Would I have been correct then?

Comment: You can reverse the polarity. `I` will be flowing out of the circuit. Then also you will get the correct answer. Instead of splitting, currents will be combining in this case.

Comment: @nidhin, one does not *have* use a test source since there are no dependent sources in this circuit.  Simply zero the independent source and *correctly* calculate the equivalent resistance seen by \$R_L\$.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri I know that. OP was having a confusion with deciding which resistors are parallel and which ones are in series. I thought a test source would help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this: [image]

Looking into 1, we have 2K || 2K = 1K

Looking into 2, we have 2K + 1K = 3K

Looking into 3, we have 3K || 2K

Comment: The mistake is is in the first line.  [(2k + 2k) || 2k] + 2k, but its really hard to tell without knowing which 2k is which in your equation. There are no two 2K resistors directly in series in the calculation.

Comment: Why did you choose to have the current entering at the top-right node?  What if I chose it to enter at the bottom-right node?

Comment: Then ground the upper right node, and see 2K || (1K + 2K) again.